# How do I return the Resolved Data with the new RXJS 6 pipe/map in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, rxjs, angular6

How do I return the Resolved Data with the new RXJS 6 pipe/map in Angular 6?

```
@Injectable()
export class RecentDataResolver implements Resolve<RecentData> {
    constructor(
        public data: DataService,
        private api: ApiService) {}

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<any> {

        this.api.get('/data/recent').pipe(map(response => {
            return response as RecentData;
        }));
      }
}
```

The data resolved is `null` when I subscribe to it in the component:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public data: DataService) {

    this.route.data.subscribe(routeData => {
      this.recent = routeData.recent;
      console.log('data', routeData.recent);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return an observable from the resolver function.

You were missing the return statement.

```
return this.api.get('/data/recent').pipe(map(response => {
     return response as RecentData;
}));
```

Comment: jeez, that was a noob mistake :P thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing any logic inside the `get()`, you may simply return it as

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {    
        return this.api.get<RecentData>('/data/recent');
}
```